# What does setting width=9999 and height=9999 do on <img>?

Tags: html, image, width

I have accidentally seen `<img src='...' width="9999" height="9999">`.
What is the purpose of setting to 9999 ?
Is it a hack?

Comment: It makes the the image very, very, large. That's really it.  (However, its dimensions may of course be altered via JavaScript after the fact and other such shenanigans.)

Comment: You "accidentally" saw it?

Comment: @j08691 - Yes, I did. I'm just debugging a website I came across online. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @middaparka - I wonder why they didn't wrap it with div or something and used width="100%"

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a hack. It will set the height and width of the specified image to be 9999px by 9999px. In otherwords, super large.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't wrap it with div or something and used width="100%"